# How to populate the template URL of a Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm using Angular2 v2.3. I'm interesting to find how to populate a template URL to a Angular2 component dynamically, for example taking by the attributes of the select tag. I was surfing on the internet and all the examples I found are related to use ComponentResolver, that's deprecated and I don't know how to do it using ComponentFactoryResolver.

Could anyone shed some light on this? I'll appreciate so much your feedbacks.

Thank you in advance